# Cannot run a Scala program in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

So I made a project in Scala -> Activator. I am trying to run it but I cannot even select it, it has a main function. When I press the alt+shift+F10 nothing happens at all.

The icon for the main.scala file also has some red thing in the bottom right corner, which I'm unsure what that means.

Also if I edit the file there is no star at the filename, like if it was unchanged.

Comment: Scala->Activator is to create a project from an Activator template. Which template did you choose? If you're just starting with Scala, better start from https://developer.lightbend.com/start/ and then open the project in IntelliJ afterwards.

Comment: At least my IntelliJ-installation is configured to automatically safe (by default!). If this is the case, changes will not produce a mark that things are unchanged...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering rather than deleting this question. I solved the problem by creating a Maven project or by using sbt, it will not run right out of the gate like Java (coming from a Java background).